# Write the signature of a method which would get a list of ingredients in a Recipe for a specific recipe. Where not all the recipes are known

Tags: c#, function, methods, signature

I am trying to create a signature of method but not able to understand the question correctly.Can some one please help me out how to do the same in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this step by step.

> Write the signature of a method

```
void MyMethod()
```

> which would get a list of ingredients

```
List<Ingredient> MyMthod()
```

> for a specific recipe

```
List<Ingredient> MyMethod(Recipe recipe)
```

> Where not all the recipes are known

```
//No change. Simply returns null if the recipe is not known
List<Ingredient> MyMethod(Recipe recipe)
```